# jquery mobile, ajax listview is not rendered quit normally

Tags: javascript, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a listview inside a page.
I'm adding an element asynchronously to that listview. and when i add it, the element is not rendered like the other element in the list:

That's the html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
    <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header Page 1</h1></div> 

    <div  data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><input type="time" /></li>
            <li><button id="add" >Add input field </button></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 

    <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div> 
</div>
```

That's the way I add the new `li` to the listview

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#p1 [data-role=listview]").append('<li><input type="time" /></li>');
    $("#p1 [data-role=listview]").listview("refresh");
});
```

Here's the js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/73pSv/21/

Also, I want to say that I need to add fields at runtime. I wont know all the input fields that go into that list before-hand. So basically, adding fields after the listview is created is what I need (as the program runs). Sorry for the confusion.

If anyone has some nice suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3K863/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
            <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header Page 1</h1></div> 

            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><input type="time" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 

            <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#p1', function(){ 
    $("[data-role='listview']").append('<li><input type="time"/></li>');
});
```

Don't use document ready with jQuery Mobile. Use appropriate page events, like **pagebeforecreate** in my case. Your problem is non-standard usage of listview. While for some reason jQuery Mobile can enhance it during page initialization it can't do it programmatically using **listview('refresh')**, at lease not in version you are using.

It's working in my example because content is appended before initial page markup enhancement process has started.

### Update:

Here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J7QrF/

This one will work because code is enhanced before appending process.

Comment: noo that's not exactly it. Sure thank's bro. but i need to add and remove fields at run time, and when i do that its not rendered correctly

Comment: well i mean, beforepagecreate wont help in this particular situation.
since, i;ll know the input fields that go there at runtime (after page creation)

Comment: sorry, i didnt read your commend about "it programmatically using listview('refresh'), at lease not in version you are using.". okay, thanks Gajotres.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it: http://jsfiddle.net/73pSv/22/

You need to add `$('#p1').trigger('create');` at the end